# SQL: Are dirty reads guaranteed to see very latest data?

Tags: sql, transactions, atomic, acid

If I open a transaction in `READ UNCOMMITTED` Isolation level, am I guaranteed to see the **latest data on every table/row**? I.e. as soon as some other transaction updates a row, my tranaction will see that change? (this would be analogous to a write-through to main memory)

Could it even be that my `SELECT` will get a row containing **part of** an `UPDATE`, but not all of it? What would in this case be the smallest element that is atomically updated/read?

Are there differences in the various relational database systems?

Comment: Even if you do get the "latest" data, by the time you can *reason* about that data, it may now be out of date. So what value is there is knowing whether it *was* the latest data at the point at which you accessed it?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and not every DBMS actually supports dirty reads. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: If accurate data is required, stay away from dirty reads.

Comment: I want another process to be able to see whether a transaction is currently going on. For that, every such transaction will write a log entry to some table at the beginning, and remove it at the end. If the transaction fails, the entry will be rolled-back too. But the outside process will be able to detect whether something is going on.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in my case it is IBM DB2, but the question is more general, as I‘m interested in the semantics. Also, that‘s why my last questions aims at differences between DBMS

Comment: @jarlh: can you explain why I should stay away from it? I am aware that the data read is potentially non-existing after the transaction is rolled-back, but that's exactly what I am aiming for...

Comment: If you know what you're doing, fine, but don't expect accurate data always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  "Dirty data" means that you are relying on the internals of the database, so there are no guarantees.  Data could be written to the data page and then removed due to a transaction rollback.  Data could be written to the data page -- and then a later step in the same transaction could overwrite it.

In addition, what you are asking for is not possible.  Your query could be scanning an entire table.  Your reads are occurring at the page level.  Each page could be a different amalgamation of transactions, with no consistency.